# Rewriting get_next_posts_link() for custom loop

Tags: pagination, query-variable

I'm trying it manipulate `get_next_posts_link()` for my custom loop.
My author page has a custom loop using query string "`?sort=selfie`". I've registered view selfie as `query_vars`.

```
http://localhost/author/ricky/selfie/
```

The first page is working fine. But the next page link returns 404 error. Currently my next page link appears as follow:

```
http://localhost/author/ricky/selfie/page/2/
```

But when I hit the following link it works well:

```
http://localhostauthor/ricky/selfie/2/?view=selfie
```

So I came up which an amateur method which itself is buggy. I modified the next_page_link() like below given code.

```
$pager=explode('"',get_next_posts_link()); 
$pager_url=$pager[1];

$newurl = str_replace('selfie/','',$pager_url); ?>
<a href="<?php echo $newurl.'?view=selfie'; ?>">Next</a>
```

But after second page it duplicates `?sort=selfie` at the end of url.

```
http://localhost/author/ricky/page/3/?sort=selfie?sort=selfie
```

Do you guys know any solution for pagination for loop using `query_vars`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what do you mean by a 'custom loop' (perhaps you are using a custom `WP_Query` object?) but here is how I would do it in a normal situation (code hasn't been tested):

***Note:*** My initial solution made use of the `add_rewrite_endpoint` function which turns out to be useless in terms of making pagination work.

```
function wt_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%selfie%', '([^&]+)');

    add_rewrite_rule( 'author/([^/]+)/selfie/page/([0-9]+)/?$', 'index.php?author_name=$matches[1]&selfie=1&paged=$matches[2]', 'top' );
    add_rewrite_rule( 'author/([^/]+)/selfie/?$', 'index.php?author_name=$matches[1]&selfie=1', 'top' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wt_rewrite_rule' );
```

As for linking to the author page from within the loop you can simply build the URL like this:

```
$author_url = esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ) . 'selfie/';
```

And you can check for the presence of that var like so:

```
global $wp_query;

if ( isset( $wp_query->query_vars['selfie'] ) ) {
    // Your custom code here
}
```

Unlike using `add_rewrite_endpoint`, your pagination should also work.

Just to be clear, as far as I understand you've mentioned that a paged link like this:

```
http://localhost/author/ricky/selfie/page/2/
```

wouldn't work. The above solution aims to fix this and make it work as expected.

Comment: I tested your rewrite function and its working. Thanks for the tip